# Has iOS Always had Secure Boot?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, startup

In Apple's recent iOS Security paper here
http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf

They speak about the Secure Boot Chain, my question is has iPhones/iPods/iPads always had this feature?

> "Secure Boot Chain Each step of the boot-up process contains
>   components that are cryptographically  signed by Apple to ensure
>   integrity, and proceeds only after verifying the chain of  trust. This
>   includes the bootloaders, kernel, kernel extensions, and baseband
>   firmware"

Answer (score 1):

The **Secure Boot Chain** is a succession of steps designed to check and verify the integrity of the iOS. As it ensures too that the iOS runs only on validated Apple device, I'd say that it has been like this since the beginning.